# WP app to manage phone like Android's AirDroid?

Tags: apps, wifi, file-transfer

I am using HTC 8S Windows Phone. Previously, I was using an Android phone and am very attached and used to using this app called "[AirDroid](http://www.airdroid.com/)"

> AirDroid is a fast, free app that lets you wirelessly manage & control your Android Device from a web browser Over-The-Air.

So my question is, is there a similar app for Windows Phone 8? How can I achieve a similar kind of functionality with Windows Phone 8?

Comment: After reading about some of the things AirDoid can do, all I can say is Windows Phone apps are much more strictly sandboxed. I think the closest app you could possibly find would only allow you access to your pictures and music.

Comment: yes I want to transfer music. Do you know of any such apps that does that.

Comment: Unfortunately... That Last "poster", doesn't know what they are advising others to do, especially when a serious question about **ALTERNATIVES** for AirDroid on Windows phone 7, since there was/is **NOTHING** found in that forum about one! I too, am looking for an alternative to AirDroid on WP7 and so far, **THERE IS NONE!** The **ONLY** thing is for us to use the **ZUNE** (the Windows way!) **App**, but it requires you to attach your WP7 phone, with a USB cable to your PC!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a 3rd party app for that. Just [synch music from the cloud](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/music/syncing-music-faq). Either [OneDrive](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2013809/windows-8-deep-dive-get-to-know-your-skydrive-app.html) or Xbox Music - both will do the job. It's not most intuitive, but perfectly doable.

Comment: will they copy the music to sd card ? i use HTC 8s and have very limited internal memory (4GB)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I don't have Windows Phone 8 phone nor ever used memory cards with a phone (I try to buy phones that meet my requirements right off the box, so don't know much about SD cards in phones at all).

Comment: ok sure.. no problem, thank you for your answer

Comment: @Yasser You should have the option to save music to SD card, or use the Files app to move it to your SD.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you can do with your phone without actually touching it. The [windowsphone](http://windowsphone.com/) website is great for that, but if you really want to actually use your phone remotely, there are a few alternatives to AirDroid. I use AlternativeTo when I have a question like this. It doesn't let me down.

http://alternativeto.net/software/airdroid/

Comment: That only seems to offer other alternative Android software, and not for other platforms, like Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0):

There is an now an app like airdroid for windows phone 8, it's called [Remote Device Manager](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=5699d17a-6a85-4720-8c77-307d1a1657a3)

Comment: "Esay transfer" for windows phone. Even though not so interactive as Airdroid, but serves the purpose

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload music to your phone over wifi from your computer (like Airdroid does), you can use [Music Drop](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=09a12ce5-26ec-4251-b7a1-16216de4c2fb).